# Guidance creating a SQL query

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query that returns userIds that have not received an offer. For example I would like to offer the `productId 1019` to my users but I do not want to offer the product to users that already received it. But the query below keeps returning the `userId = 1054` and it should only return `userId=3333`. I will appreciate any help.

**Users**:

```
  Id        Status
   -----------------
  1054       Active
  2222       Active
  3333       Active
```

**Offers**:

```
 userId   ProductId
 --------------------
 1054       1019
 1054       1026
 2222       1019
 3333       1026
```

Query

```
DECLARE @i int = 1019

SELECT Distinct c.id 
FROM Users c  
INNER JOIN offers o ON c.id = o.UserId  
WHERE o.ProductId NOT IN (@i) 
ORDER BY c.id
```

Comment: Just to clarify.  Your expected result is only `3333`, but you are actually getting both `3333 1054`?

Comment: ryanyuyu , thank you for your response, yes I should only get 3333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1019

SELECT c.id
FROM
  Users c LEFT JOIN offers o  
  ON c.id = o.UserId  
  AND o.ProductId IN (@i)
WHERE
  o.UserId IS NULL
ORDER BY
  c.id
```

Please see an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/280cf/1).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a SQLFiddle to show how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb79b/3

```
select
  c.id
from
  Users c
where
  c.id not in (
    select
      o.userid
    from
      Offers o  
    where o.ProductId = @i
  )
order by c.id
```

Comment: Upvoted, but the left join should be compared if performance is a concern. In my experience, left joins are faster.

Comment: Guys, all the responses work! Thank you so much!  I wish I can mark all the responses. I truly appreciate it.  Have an excellent weekend!

Comment: That's true, but I like the readability of using NOT IN in this case.

Comment: NOt exists is often faster

Comment: I was thinking about using "not exists", but I didn't want to create a correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is lacking is you should use a left join instead of an inner join

Go check the example here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left

If you replace,in the example in the link, the `ORDER BY` with a `WHERE Orders.OrderID IS NULL` you get something similar to what you are looking for. Run the SQL in there and try different things with their data it will help you a lot a lot understanding how the different types of join work